# tycho & jar signing

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, maven-3, tycho

I'm using maven & tyhco to compile & build my eclipse plugins and create a p2 repository.

However, when I install my plugins, eclipse shows a warning for the untrusted content. I know that to solve this issue, I must sign the plugins I distribute.

However, I don't know if there is a way to sign the plugins I'm building with tycho...

(I'm not an expert on maven & jar signing, hence forgive me for the dumb question!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see a working example in [The Mylyn-Mantis connector pom.xml](https://github.com/Mylyn-Mantis/mylyn-mantis/blob/master/pom.xml) . I have a special profile for signing:

```
    <profile>
        <id>sign</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>jarsigner.alias</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>sign</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>sign</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Typically I invoke the sign command as `mvn clean package -Djarsigner.alias=... -Djarsigner.storepass=... -Djarsigner.keypass=....` .

You also need to have a code signing certificate, whcih you will import using `keytool -trustcacerts -importcert -file $CERTIFICATE -alias $ALIAS -keystore keystore.jks`.

Comment: Thank you: now I'm able to sign plugins and feature... but I forgot to say that I'm building an RCP application, and it fails because "One or more certificates rejected. Cannot proceed with installation." Do you know how I can add certificates to my RCP app?

Comment: @Matteo - sorry, I have no idea about that.

Comment: Googling around, it seems it is a bug of tycho/eclipse/(oracle) jvm...  anyway, the original question has been answered (even if I cannot use it for my RCP app ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same needs : sign p2 bundle in an eclipse build process.
You can use the eclipse way: https://www.eclipse.org/cbi/sitedocs/eclipse-jarsigner-plugin/sign-mojo.html

Wich is used by eclipse it self to sign their bundles :
https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator/blob/master/eclipse-platform-parent/pom.xml